# RxJava Single.create cannot specify thread

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

Below initialize() method was working great, but it has to work on the same io thread (ioScheduler) as the other calls.

```
fun initialize(): Single<Boolean> {
    return Single.create { callback ->
                callback.onSuccess(true)
    }
}
```

I've tried changing it to this code:

```
internal fun initialize(): Single<Boolean> {
    return Single.create<Any> { singleEmitter ->
        singleEmitter.onSuccess(true)
    }
    .observeOn(ioScheduler) 
    .subscribe() as Single<Boolean>
}
```

But that creates a new problem:

ConsumerSingleObserver cannot be cast to io.reactivex.Single

I've also tried this:

```
    Completable.fromAction { someMethod() }
            .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
            .subscribe()
```

But that doesn't return the boolean value.

Comment: How is `subscribeOn`not working for you with `Single.create()`?

Comment: Jim, long time no see

Comment: @TimCastelijns Graduated already? ;) If so, please solve this. I know you can do it ;)

Comment: Yep! Not really into kotlin and rxjava though

Comment: Single<T>.subscribe() does not return Single<T>.
It returns observer.
Why would you need this Single after subscription?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
internal fun initialize(): Single<Boolean> {
    return Single.create<Boolean> { singleEmitter ->
        singleEmitter.onSuccess(true)
    }
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
}
```

The output is boolean so you should specify `<Boolean>` as the exact type parameter to `create`. In addition, you should simply return the chain and not subscribe to it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are calling the method from UI thread, than you will not receive the Boolean, as you have subscribed Completable on IO thread, you should observe it on UI thread explicitly